# How to set image for whole ionic 3 app?

Tags: angular, ionic3, background-image

How can I set an image as a background for the whole application? I tried to set in `ion-content` but it set an image to content only. It omits header and tabs. I want to set it for the whole view. For that I have tired in `ion-page, .tabs, .show-tab` but nothing helps. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can set background image in `.ion-page` class and then after set `background-color:transparent` for content, header and tabs main class.

Comment: I tried with both .ion-page and ion-page but it is not showing. If I change it to .show-content it is showing in content only

Comment: Can you paste you code I have tried like .ion-page{
    background-color: transparent  !important;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    background-image: url("../assets/imgs/default-background/default-background-image.jpg") !important; background-size: cover; 
}

Comment: I tried with this .ion-page {background-image: url(../assets/imgs/home-bg.jpg);background-color: transparent;background-repeat: no-repeat;}

Comment: Thank you. I have changed other back ground to transparent and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Header and Tabs are the components simply put over the content, that is, you cannot combine them with content but you can make them transparent to make underlying image visible.

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar transparent>
    <ion-title>Meu App</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Like this, or just use the css to make it as you wish.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick response

Answer (score 0):

This will set the background for the full content area.

```
.scroll-content {
        background: url(image);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.